# Add quotes to item in list - Python

Tags: python, pandas

How do you add quotes "" to each item in the list? I'm getting the data from an excel file using pandas then converting it to a list. I've added a picture of the excel file and the output I'm getting. I've also added the desired output. How can I achieve this?

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np


path = r'C:\Temp Files\Excel_2.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path).replace('"','')


res = (df.dropna(how='all') #remove completely empty rows
.dropna(how='all',axis=1) #remove completely empty columns
.T #flip columns into row position
#convert to list    
.to_numpy()
.tolist()

)

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT**

`[[nan, 'Title_1', 'RED_100', Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), 10], [nan, 'Title_2', 'GREEN_200', Timestamp('2018-02-02 00:00:00'), 20], [nan, 'Title_3', 'RED_300', Timestamp('2019-11-15 00:00:00'), 30], [123456, 'Title_4', 'YELLOW_100', Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), 40]]`

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

`[[nan, "Title_1", "RED_100", "Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')", "10"],[nan, "Title_2", "GREEN_200", "Timestamp('2018-02-02 00:00:00')", "20"],[nan, "Title_3", "RED_300", "Timestamp('2019-11-15 00:00:00')", "30"],["123456", "Title_4", "YELLOW_100", "Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')", "40"]]`

**Excel File**

[image]

Comment: I think you should look into regular expressions (`re` module).

Comment: Where did this "string" come from?  It almost looks like some sort of serialized data ... but not _quite_.  More context would help a ton.

Comment: You could look at the f" string notation with which you could put curly brackets around your datetime to achieve this.

Comment: I attached the answer @g.d.d.c

Comment: Don't try to do string manipulation on the result of `print(res)`.  Just do things to `res` directly; it will be much easier.  (e.g. `[[f'"{col}"' for col in row] for row in res]`)

Comment: I was thinking that and was researching how to do it, but no luck  @0x5453

Comment: `pd.read_excel` should have an option that is doing what you want. Otherwise, there should be a `pd.read_*` which does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by changing

`df = pd.read_excel(path).replace('"','')`

to

`df = pd.read_excel(path, dtype=str)`

adding `dtype=str` changes all the values into a string and adds the quotes around that data